# Multi-window drag and drop in android N

Tags: android, multi-window, android-7.0-nougat

Android N announced **multi-window drag and drop** feature, where we can drag and drop objects between activities.

This is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B08iLAtS3AQ) of Google-IO'16 where they show the demo (9:56).

**Do we have to do anything special to enable this feature in our app or we normally listen for Drop events** (Assuming that I only want people to drop into my app from other apps ?

Can anyone give a link to the code sample for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do we have to do anything special to enable this feature in our app or we normally listen for Drop events

Assuming that you are using `setOnDragListener()`, your app will receive drop events regardless of origin (from within your app or from another app).

Note that you will want to call `requestDragAndDropPermissions()` in your `ACTION_DROP` handling, so that you have rights to any content referenced in the `DragEvent`. That is not necessary for in-app drop events, and it probably is not needed for simple text drop events between apps, but it becomes important for drag-and-drop of content represented by `Uri` values.

> Can anyone give a link to the code sample for this ?

[This project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DragDrop/Permissions) has a pair of app modules. `drag/` implements an activity that allows you to drag a photo from an `ImageView` via a long-click gesture. `drop/` implements an activity that accepts the dragged image. The image is shared via a `FileProvider`.